# Programmatically create subclasses

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a set of similar pages (webcomics). Because these pages are *very* similar, I wrote a class called `ComicCrawler` which contains all the spider logic and some class variables (`start_url`, `next_selector`, etc.). I then override these class variables in concrete classes for each spider.

Manually creating classes for each comic is cumbersome. I now want to specify the attributes in a JSON file and create the classes during runtime (ie. *apply the factory pattern (?)*) How do I best go about that?

Alternatively: Is there a way to run a spider without creating a class for it? *Edit:* The core problem seems to be that Scrapy uses classes, not instances for its spiders. Otherwise I'd just make the class variables instance variables and be done with it.

---

Example:

```
class ComicSpider(Spider):
  name = None
  start_url = None
  next_selector = None
  # ...

  # this class contains much more logic than shown here

  def start_requests(self):
    # something including / along the lines of...
    yield Request (self.start_url, self.parse)

  def parse(self, response):
    # something including / along the lines of...
    yield Request(response.css(self.next_selector).get(), self.parse)
```

in another file:

```
class SupernormalStep(ComicSpider):
  name = "SupernormalStep"
  start_url = "https://supernormalstep.com/archives/8"
  next_selector = "a.cc-next"
```

what I want:

```
myComics = {
  "SupernormalStep": {
    "start_url": "https://supernormalstep.com/archives/8",
    "next_selector": "a.cc-next"
  }, # ...
}

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
for name, attributes in myComics:
  process.crawl(build_process(name, attributes))
```

PS: I crawl responsibly.

Comment: Is the attributes in your class are dynamic?

Comment: No, they are defined statically, probably in a JSON file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class` statement is a declarative wrapper around using `type` directly. Assuming `process.crawl` takes a class as an argument,

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
for name, attributes in myComics.items():
    process.crawl(type(name, (ComicSpider,), attributes))
```

`type(name, (ComicSpider,), attributes)` will create a class with name `name`, that will inherit from `ComicSpider` and will have attributes as defined in the `attributes` dictionary. [An example on Python docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

Comment: You are right, this is much simpler than creating a metaclass.

Comment: I added `.items()` to `myComics` but other than that it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Look up metaclasses. This is the way in Python to dynamically create new classes. [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

For this simpler case there is a simpler method which is described in [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55130640/10687003).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be what I need. I'll type up my implementation as a separate answer once I figure it out.

Comment: Metaclasses would seem to be overkill for this task.